# Closure contained in open set of $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am currently reading a proof of the [Hyperplane separation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem). It uses the following:

If $X\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ is a  convex set containing $0$, and  $\alpha\in (0,1)$, then the closure of $\alpha X:=\{\alpha x\mid x\in X\}$ is contained in $X$.

This seems highly intuitive. However, I am unable to verify it formally. Any hint on how it can be proven?

Comment: This is probably not a terribly elegant argument, but my first inclination is to think "If $x \in \alpha X$, then $y= \frac{1}{\alpha}x \in X$, and $x$ is on the segment through $0$ and $y$.  Apply convexity."

Comment: @XanderHenderson The problem is we're talking about the closure of $\alpha X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is true without further conditions on $X$. Suppose:
$$X = \big\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y > 0\big\} \cup \{(0,0)\},$$
i.e. that $X$ consists of everything strictly above the $x$-axis in the plane, union the origin.  $X$ is convex, but for any $\alpha > 0$ the closure of $\alpha X$ is everything weakly above the $x$-axis, which is not contained in $X$.

Comment: Wow, nice example!